# Pandas .loc with list values throwing "ValueError: Lengths must match to compare" error

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a Pandas DataFrame where on column has lists for values. Some of the values are nonempty lists and some are empty lists. I want to extract only the rows that contain nonempty lists for this specific column, but am getting an error when I run the code that I expected to do the job.

The code that I run is:

```
df.loc[df['column'] != []]
```

This gives me the error:

```
ValueError: Lengths must match to compare.
```

Taking the error message into account, I tried:

```
df.loc[len(df['column']) != 0]
```

and get

```
KeyError: True
```

I'm a bit confused as I thought my initial attempt would work, and I'm not sure what exactly is the problem. How might I go about this issue? Thanks in advance.

#### EDIT

I actually just noticed that I get the  `ValueError: Lengths must match to compare` error everytime I try to perform the `df.loc` operation with any of the values in the column of lists.

Comment: Do you have a  df[0:2].to_dict()  that you could share to evaluate?

Comment: Are you looking to get the length of all the True values of the series, then looking up that location

Comment: I randomly stumbled here again, but I think you forgot to mark an answer as accepted!

Answer (score 3):

Try this i tested on columns with empty lists on a dataframe i have:

```
df[df['column'].astype(str) != '[]']
```

Comment: Probably faster than using apply, and even works in cases where list contains numpy.nan. Weird that Pandas doesn't give a better way to compare columns of lists.

Answer (score 2):

The part you put inside `loc` needs to return a list, that is as long as there are rows in your dataframe with `True` and `False` values. That is how it selects the right rows.

Your problem is that `df['column'] != []` can't be done, because it would like to compare the two element by element.

`len(df['column']) != 0` also doesn't work, because this returns a single value (`True` since you have more than 0 values in the column).

What you need is to have a list with the lengths of the lists, so something like `df['column'].apply(lambda x:len(x))`, which you can now compare with 0.

Here's an example you can run:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'trial_num': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
     'subject': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
     'column': [list(np.random.randn(3).round(2)) for i in range(6)]
    }
)

df["column"][3] = []
print(df["trial_num"] == [1,2,3,4,5,6])
print(df['column'].apply(lambda x:len(x)) != 0)
print(df.loc[df['column'].apply(lambda x:len(x)) != 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
df.loc[df['column'].str.len() != 0]
```